# Using in-place lambda for complex initialisation, especially consts

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

In-place lambdas can be used for complex initialisation. So you can do something like this:

```
const widget x = [&]{
    widget val;                                // assume that widget has a default constructor
    for (auto i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {            // this could be some
        val += some_obj.do_something_with(i);  // arbitrarily long code
    }                                          // needed to initialize x
    return val; }();
```

This is better than writing something like this:

```
widget x;   // should be const, but:
for (auto i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {             // this could be some
    x += some_obj.do_something_with(i);  // arbitrarily long code
}                                        // needed to initialize x
// from here, x should be const, but we can't say so in code in this style
```

According to the [blog](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-function-objects-and-lambas) where I read this, the former bit of code is thread safe. This avoids having to use expensive synchronisation. So you wouldn't need to use mutex locking for the latter bit of code to ensure synchronisation.

My question is what makes the former thread safe? How does it work?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how it's implemented, or how it's specified as thread safe?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica How is it implemented? There's no explicit synchronisation as you can see. So why is it thread safe?

Comment: _You can not change its value and ,therefore, you can use it in a multithreading program without expensive synchronisation._ The blog refers to the fact that `widget` is `const` not anything specific to lambda expressions.

Comment: Presence of absence of `const` qualifier tells nothing about thread safety of access to specific variable. And the way variable has been initialized has nothing to do with it. Maybe that blog post was aimed at thread safe initialization of globals and statics, but in this case using lamba would be even more pointless than use of lamba for initialization of local variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the "blog" referred to the assumption that the usage of a `const` object should involve only read operations and, therefore, should be safely usable in multiple threads without synchronization. This is the last sentence from that "blog" part:

> You **can not change its value** and, therefore, you **can use it in a multithreading program without expensive synchronization**.

However, this statement is, generally, incorrect. As pointed out by @VTT, classes may have `mutable` member variables, or, e.g., reference member variables. There is thus no general guarantee that a `const` object can be safely used in a multi-threaded code without synchronization.

You may also notice that the corresponding Item [ES.28](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init) in C++ Core Guidelines does not mention multi-threading at all in the context of this problem.

Comment: This answer is misleading. `const widget x` can be modified in the future if it has mutable fields. Iven if it does not have mutable fields then it may hold references to mutable shared state so presence of absence of const qualifier tells nothing about thread safety of access to specific variable.

Comment: Well, *"You can not change its value and ,therefore, you can use it in a multithreading program without expensive synchronisation."* statement can only be applied to primitive types such as int or pointer. It is wrong in general case because even `this` object is not modified method invocation may change shared mutable state.

Comment: @VTT I completely rewrote my answer to reflect you comments. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the explanation. So what I understand now is that the object, beacuse it is constant, can be used safely by multiple threads. However, the initialisation is not thread-safe per se. Is that correct?

Comment: @jignatius No, that was the point of VTT. Even if the object is constant, it cannot be safely used by multiple threads **without synchronization, in general**. It holds, e.g., for fundamental object types, such as integers. But not generally for classes. The initialization itself has nothing to do with threading. Note that `x` is an object with _automatic storage duration_.

Comment: @jignatius Consider [this demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PUiADiwm3vvNpPPj). It has a data race and therefore undefined behavior, though `x` used in a thread is a `const` object.

Comment: @DanielLangr So the blog is misleading. If the object is a fundamental type it will be threadsafe because its value can be known at compile time. If the object has a constexpr constructor and other methods it will be threadsafe if the lambda uses those methods?

Comment: @VTT, actually, `const` does tell something, or, rather, should tell. See this talk by Herb Sutter: [You don't know `const` and `mutable`](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank). The point is: starting from C++11, anything that is marked as `const`, should be thread-safe by design (either bitwise const or internally synchronized).

Comment: @jignatius Yes, I think it is misleading. As for `constexpr`, `const` and `constexpr` are different concepts, so maybe, you should ask a separate question about it.

Comment: @Evg I agree with this concept. However, consider the [already mentioned demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PUiADiwm3vvNpPPj). The object `x` is _bitwise-const_ there, but its usage is not thread-safe. Does Herb mean that `X` must synchronize access to `i`, which is just referenced by `x`? He does not mention such a case with references.

Comment: @Evg After watching this video a couple of times I'm gonna make a bold statement that Herb Sutter is wrong there. The issue arises around 10:30 where he somehow jumps from "C ++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non-const arguments..." to conclusion that operations involved must be thread-safe.

Comment: If these operations use internal synchronization then they would directly violate library requirement by modifying object (indirectly) accessed through a const argument. Also note that that library requirement is only applied to objects  accessible by threads other than the current thread.

Comment: @DanielLangr, and how can `X` synchronize access to `i`?

Comment: @Evg By a reference to an outer mutex, for example. My point was that even _bitwise-const_ does not generally guarantee thread safety.